# Can a formal parameter have the same name as a type? (C)

Tags: c, typedef

I'm not arguing that this is good programming style, but I was surprised that this compiled[*] and ran without complaint:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define function signature
typedef int (*proto_fn)();

int x() { return 22; }

// Note: type name and formal parameter name are the same
void printit(proto_fn proto_fn) { 
  printf("%d\n", proto_fn());
}

int main() {
  printit(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Aside from potentially confusing humans, is there anything in the C standard that would forbid using identical names for a type and a formal parameter?

[*] (In this case, Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8).)

Comment: I think this is related to the issue about which either K or R famously wrote, "It is agreed the ice is thin here."

Comment: After the function parameter is defined, the name `proto_fn` in that function is no longer a type but the variable, so you can't declare another pointer to function using the type name `proto_fn` in the body of the function.  Incidentally, note that the pointer is not prototyped — not strictly prototyped.  The number of arguments to the function is fixed, not variable, but the types are unspecified.  Use `typedef int (*proto_fn)(void);` to give a prototype for functions that take no arguments.  (Neither the definition of `x()` nor `main()` provides a prototype either.)

Comment: Use `-Wshadow` to get warnings about shadowing variables and types.  Heed the warnings.  But what you're doing is legal — inadvisable, but legal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "note that the pointer is not ... strictly prototyped. ... Use `typedef int (*proto_fn)(void);` to give a prototype for functions that take no arguments."  File under "one new thing I learned todday" -- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to check whether the name `proto_fn` stands for a type name or an variable of the type `proto_fn`, inside the function `printit`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define function signature
typedef int (*proto_fn)();

int x() { return 22; }

// Note: type name and formal parameter name are the same
void printit(proto_fn proto_fn) 
{ 
  printf("%d\n", proto_fn());
  proto_fn;

}

int main() {
  printit(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Above code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define function signature
typedef int (*proto_fn)();

int x() { return 22; }

// Note: type name and formal parameter name are the same
void printit(proto_fn proto_fn) 
{ 
  printf("%d\n", proto_fn());
  proto_fn kk;

}

int main() {
  printit(x);
  return 0;
}
```

But this code throws an error :
`error: expected ‘;’ before ‘kk’`
`proto_fn kk;`

So, from this I concluded that the name `proto_fn` is just a variable of the type `proto_fn`, inside the function `printit`. I think the type `proto_fn` is not visible, inside the function `printit` .  I think variable `proto_fn` shadows the type `proto_fn` inside the function `printit`.  This might be the reason, why the code works.

Comment: That is correct.  As @Jonathan-Leffler commented above: "After the function parameter is defined, the name proto_fn in that function is no longer a type but the variable, so you can't declare another pointer to function using the type name proto_fn in the body of the function."